# Group by with linq to update collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a IEnumerable collection called allEventsDetails and collection properties 
are Digit, Name and status.

I need to update the same collection if Two or more Digits values are equal.

```
var categories =  from p in allEventsDetails
                  group p by p.Digit into g
                  where g.Count() > 1
                  select g.Select(s => s.status = "true");
```

How can I use linq to do this?

Comment: linkq is usually used to retrieve data ... updation is not possible using LINQ... only posible way to update data through a linq query is through a extention method

Comment: LINQ is a query language, it doesn't make any modifications. Modifications are performed by the ORM you are using and are specific to it. What ORM are you using? If you are using an in-memory collection on the other hand, just modify the property

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
(from x in allEventsDetails
  group x by x.Digit into y
  where y.Count()>1
  select y).SelectMany(z=>z).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Status="true");
```

What you could also do is:

```
var temp= (from x in allEventsDetails
  group x by x.Digit into y
  where y.Count()>1
  select y).SelectMany(z=>z);

  foreach (var x in temp)
  {
     x.Status= "test";
  }
```

This way you don't have to create a "temporary" list.

Comment: `ForEach` is a method on `List`, not part of LINQ. There is no need to create a temporary list though, just iterate over the result and set the status.

Comment: Yes you could. Just updating in a single "batch". Well, LINQ is just a syntatic sugar on top of C# and compilers later translates it into series of extension methods to Enumerable/Querable anyway.

Comment: @Aruns see my updated answer for what Panagiotis meant